# KNIME Databricks community connection

Tags: databricks, knime, databricks-connect

I've been using Databricks Community cluster Environment from Knime for weeks.

I don't know why now it's not possible and an unexpected error message appears in the console log of Knime.

```
ERROR Create Databricks Environment 2:1        Execute failed: Unable to upload job jar
```

If I uncheck the Spark Create Spark Context checkmark, the connection is established, so, I guess it's something related to Spark.

Nevertheless, the same versions of Knime, Databricks and other Libraries are used.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance

.

Comment: Solved!! I just deleted and created again the ACCOUNT in Databricks Community.

Comment: Probably some error in configuration files or internal Databricks were changed unintentionally. It is strange, but ... well, as I said, deleting the account and re-creating everything works again.
In any case, thank you and I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments above. Eventually, I had to delete and create again the community account to solve the issue.
If you need to do that, download and save all the notebooks etc. you have in the account before to re-create it.